# Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x170033420 :: NSOperation 0x17405fe00 (QOS: DEFAULT)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a function in a Swift 3.0 based iOS app that is supposed to send HTTP requests and handle them via completion blocks once the values are returned from the server. However, I cannot reproduce this crash in-house but with users, I see it constantly happening. The line number in the code is marked with Crashes here in the code snippet below. Any debugging suggestions or clues?

```
func sendRequest(_ parameters : NSDictionary?, requestType : String, urlString : String, completionHandler : @escaping (_ succeeded : Bool, _ response : [String : AnyObject]?) -> ()) {
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
  request.httpMethod = requestType
  request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
  request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
  if let jsonParams = parameters {
    do {
      request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonParams, options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch {
      self.log.error("Error -> \(error).")
      completionHandler(false, nil)
    }
  }

  let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    if error != nil {
      self.log.error("Error -> \(error?.localizedDescription)")
      completionHandler(false, nil)
    }

    do {
      //  -----> Crashes here - not sure why?
      let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String : AnyObject]
      completionHandler(true, result)
    } catch {
      self.log.error("Error -> \(error).")
      completionHandler(false, nil)
    }
  })
  task.resume()
}
```

}

Stack trace of crashed thread:

```
Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x170033420 :: NSOperation 0x17405fe00 (QOS: DEFAULT)
0  Jarvis                         0x1000a6d74 specialized ContextServer.(sendRequest(NSDictionary?, requestType : String, urlString : String, completionHandler : (Bool, [String : AnyObject]?) -> ()) -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1) (ContextServer.swift:39)
1  Jarvis                         0x1000a5e88 ContextServer.(sendRequest(NSDictionary?, requestType : String, urlString : String, completionHandler : (Bool, [String : AnyObject]?) -> ()) -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1) (ContextServer.swift)
2  CFNetwork                      0x19063e618 __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
3  CFNetwork                      0x190655318 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 296
4  Foundation                     0x190b017e4 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
5  Foundation                     0x190a46358 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 96
6  Foundation                     0x190a36954 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 620
7  Foundation                     0x190b03b90 __NSOQSchedule_f + 228
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18eec91c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x18eed7444 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x18eecc9a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x18eed938c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x18eed90ec _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18f0d12c8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18f0d0db4 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: What does a stack trace for the crashed thread look like?

Comment: Just added the stack trace for the crashed thread.

Comment: I'm immediately suspicious of the `data!` in your JSONSerialization line. How do you guarantee that it is not `nil`? My first guess is that you're getting a successful HTTP response code with `nil` data for some conditions.

Comment: Good point -> stupid me. I will guard against that. I did that elsewhere in the code but forgot to do it there.

Comment: @inc_london how did you guard against that. I am facing it too. I already have a check on it. i-e if(data != nil){} does this work?

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple has stated Data will never be nil. If anything it will be a 0 byte Data object.